# Post de variable json omite una de las variables

Tags: php, ajax, json, variables, post

Necesito enviar por post una variable nombre, dentro de un json, a un script php. Posteriormente debe insertarse en la base de datos. 
Ahora mismo logro que se propaguen el id y el email, pero el nombre no.

El formulario HTML es el siguiente:

```
<div class="text-center"  v-show="email_locker">
                <p class="text-center"><?php _e('Enter your email to download this file!', 'onyxfiles'); ?></p>
                <div v-show="show_alert" class="alert {{ alert_class }}">{{ alert_message }}</div>
                <form id="jkof_emailDLForm" novalidate v-on:submit.prevent="submit_email">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><?php _e('Enter E-mail', 'onyxfiles'); ?></label>
                        <input type="email" id="jkof_inputEmail" class="form-control" name="jkof_email" style="width:100%;">
                        <label>Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" id="jkof_inputName" class="form-control" name="jkof_name" style="width:100%;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="rcw-purple rcw-medium rcw-button-7 btn-block">
                            <span class="icon-bg"></span><span class="button-icon fa fa-envelope"></span> <?php _e('Submit & Download File', 'onyxfiles'); ?>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <button type="button" class="rcw-silver rcw-small rcw-button-7 btn-block" v-on:click="go_back('email_locker')">
                    <span class="icon-bg"></span><span class="button-icon fa fa-arrow-left"></span> <?php _e('Go Back', 'onyxfiles'); ?>
                </button>
            </div>
```

La función javaScript que envía el json por post es ésta:

```
 submit_email:                                   function(){
            this.show_alert                         =   true;
            this.alert_class                        =   'alert-info';
            this.alert_message                      =   jkof_dl_i18n.wait + ' ' + jkof_dl_i18n.adding_email;

            var formObj                             =   {
                action:                                 'jkof_check_email',
                fid:                                    this.file_id,
                jkof_email:                             $("#jkof_inputEmail").val(),
                jkof_name:                              $("#jkof_inputName").val()
            };

            $.post( jkof_ajax_url, formObj, function(data){
                if(data.status == 2){ // Instant
                    app.alert_class                 =   'alert-success';
                    app.alert_message               =   jkof_dl_i18n.success + ' ' + jkof_dl_i18n.getting_download;
                    app.check_download(app.file_id);
                }else if(data.status == 3){
                    app.alert_class                 =   'alert-success';
                    app.alert_message               =   jkof_dl_i18n.success + ' ' + jkof_dl_i18n.emailing_download;
                }else{
                    app.alert_class                 =   'alert-danger';
                    app.alert_message               =   jkof_dl_i18n.denied;
                }
            });
        }
```

Y este es el PHP que recibe y gestiona los datos, pero no recoge el nombre:

```
function jkof_check_email(){
global $wpdb;
$output                     =   array('status' => 1);
$email                      =   secure($_POST['jkof_email']);
$nomb                       =   $_POST['jkof_name'];
$fid                        =   intval($_POST['fid']);
$file_settings              =   get_post_meta( $fid, 'jkof_dl_settings', true );
$jkof_settings              =   get_option( 'jkof_settings' );
$fields                     =   array();

if(empty($file_settings) || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $output['swag']=$email;
    wp_send_json($output);
}

/*if(empty($nomb)) {
    wp_send_json($output);
}*/

$domain_email               =    array_pop(explode('@', $email));
if(in_array($domain_email, $jkof_settings['blocked']['domains']) || in_array($email, $jkof_settings['blocked']['emails'])){
    wp_send_json($output);
}

foreach( $_POST as $fk => $fv ){
    if($fk == 'jkof_email'){
        array_push($fields, array(
            'email'     =>  $email,
            'name'      => $nomb
        ));
        continue;
    }
}

$wpdb->insert( 
    $wpdb->prefix . 'of_emails', 
    array( 
        'form_fields'   =>    json_encode($fields),
        'fid'           =>    $fid,
        "time_sent"     =>    time()
    ), 
    array( '%s', '%d', '%d' ) 
);
```

No sé que puede ser, porque el problema está entre el json y el php que recoge por post los datos, no recibe el dato, aunque en lugar de la variable le ponga un texto fijo, no llega al php.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar la consola de depuración de tu navegador para ver qué información se envía en la petición XHR? Dime el navegador que usas y te digo cómo obtener esa información.

Comment: Pues la verdad que eso no, Google Chrome es lo que estoy usando, cómo haría? Gracias!

Comment: Pulsa control + mayusculas + J y en el apartado que se abre selecciona la pestaña "network". Ahí tendrás todas y cada una de las peticiones que se hacen en tu página. Marca XHR para ver sólo ese tipo de peticiones. Provoca que se envíen los datos y verás aparecer una petición, pulsa en ella y en la primera pestaña verás "Headers". Al final del todo aparecen los datos enviados. Dime cuáles son o pégalos en la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, por lo que veo no manda nada por post  action:jkof_check_email
fid:18104
jkof_email:email@mail.es

Comment: Vale, eso me confirma la parte de tu código errónea (la llamada a `$post`). Paso a redactar la respuesta con la solución a tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

El problema que sufres es debido a la forma en la que `jQuery.post()` trata los valores `undefined`.

Al ejecutar tu llamada [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) (te recomiendo usar `$.ajax` para gestionar mejor problemas de conexión, etc con un código más claro) hay datos que quedan como `undefined` (en tu caso `$("#jkof_inputEmail").val()`) porque se dejan en blanco, no encuentra ese elemento, o porque `$` (la función "madre" de `jQuery`) no está definido en ese ámbito. Sea cual sea el problema esa llamada devuelve `undefined` (al menos a mí lo hacía) y `jQuery` elimina todos los elementos del envío cuyo valor sea `undefined` y los ignora.

Por otro lado estás cometiendo errores básicos como no definir en el `$scope` variables y luego asignarlas al valor de los campos `<input>` que necesites.

No tienes que hacer uso de `jQuery` para acceder al contenido de un campo de formulario. Asígnale un dato del `$scope` con [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D) y úsalo.

Por último, recuerda usar [`$scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) para aplicar los cambios en la vista inmediatamente tras actualizar variables del `$scope`.

En este ejemplo te dejo mis sugerencias para que las revises y las apliques a tu código.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  /* Si no los definimos inicialmente darán "undefined" */
  $scope.jkof_inputEmail = '';
  $scope.jkof_inputName = '';
  $scope.file_id = 0;
  $scope.submit_email = function() {
    var jkof_ajax_url = 'https://httpbin.org/post';
    this.show_alert = true;
    this.alert_class = 'alert-info';
    //this.alert_message = jkof_dl_i18n.wait + ' ' + jkof_dl_i18n.adding_email;

    var formObj = {
      action: 'jkof_check_email',
      fid: this.file_id,
      jkof_email: this.jkof_inputEmail,
      jkof_name: this.jkof_inputName
    };
    $.post(jkof_ajax_url, formObj, function(data) {
      $scope.alert_message = data.form;
      $scope.$apply();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="text-center" v-show="email_locker">
  <p class="text-center">Enter your email to download this file!</p>
  <pre v-show="show_alert" class="alert {{ alert_class }}">{{ alert_message|json }}</pre>
  <form id="jkof_emailDLForm" ng-submit="submit_email()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter E-mail</label>
      <input type="email" ng-model="jkof_inputEmail" id="jkof_inputEmail" class="form-control" name="jkof_email" style="width:100%;" value="">
      <label>Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="jkof_inputName" id="jkof_inputName" class="form-control" name="jkof_name" style="width:100%;" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="rcw-purple rcw-medium rcw-button-7 btn-block">
        <span class="icon-bg"></span><span class="button-icon fa fa-envelope"></span> Submit &amp; Download File
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <button type="button" class="rcw-silver rcw-small rcw-button-7 btn-block" v-on:click="go_back('email_locker')">
    <span class="icon-bg"></span><span class="button-icon fa fa-arrow-left"></span> Go Back
  </button>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

he estado integrando esa parte de código, el problema viene que en conjunto no funciona con el resto del sistema, y entonces aún se complica más, he probado en el código js a introducir la variable manualmente

jkof_name:                              'hello',

O incluso metiendo en la llamada a $.post( jkof_ajax_url, {variables...}, function(data){

cualquiera que no sea las 3 que funciona no las hace caso, lo cual ahora mismo no tengo la menor idea de porque sucede, que le pase esas variables y no

Al final la llamada al post, todo esto está dentro de un wordpress lo hace al archivo admin_ajax.php del propio WP cuyo código es este y que ni aún pasándole por argumentos dentro de la llamada las variables la logro propagar.

```
<?php
```

/**
 * WordPress Ajax Process Execution
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
 */

/**
 * Executing Ajax process.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 */
define( 'DOING_AJAX', true );
if ( ! defined( 'WP_ADMIN' ) ) {
    define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );
}

/** Load WordPress Bootstrap */
require_once( dirname( dirname( **FILE** ) ) . '/wp-load.php' );

/** Allow for cross-domain requests (from the front end). */
send_origin_headers();

// Require an action parameter
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    die( '0' );

/** Load WordPress Administration APIs */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php' );

/** Load Ajax Handlers for WordPress Core */
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php' );

@header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ) );
@header( 'X-Robots-Tag: noindex' );

send_nosniff_header();
nocache_headers();

/** This action is documented in wp-admin/admin.php */
do_action( 'admin_init' );

$core_actions_get = array(
    'fetch-list', 'ajax-tag-search', 'wp-compression-test', 'imgedit-preview', 'oembed-cache',
    'autocomplete-user', 'dashboard-widgets', 'logged-in',
);

$core_actions_post = array(
    'oembed-cache', 'image-editor', 'delete-comment', 'delete-tag', 'delete-link',
    'delete-meta', 'delete-post', 'trash-post', 'untrash-post', 'delete-page', 'dim-comment',
    'add-link-category', 'add-tag', 'get-tagcloud', 'get-comments', 'replyto-comment',
    'edit-comment', 'add-menu-item', 'add-meta', 'add-user', 'closed-postboxes',
    'hidden-columns', 'update-welcome-panel', 'menu-get-metabox', 'wp-link-ajax',
    'menu-locations-save', 'menu-quick-search', 'meta-box-order', 'get-permalink',
    'sample-permalink', 'inline-save', 'inline-save-tax', 'find_posts', 'widgets-order',
    'save-widget', 'delete-inactive-widgets', 'set-post-thumbnail', 'date_format', 'time_format',
    'wp-remove-post-lock', 'dismiss-wp-pointer', 'upload-attachment', 'get-attachment',
    'query-attachments', 'save-attachment', 'save-attachment-compat', 'send-link-to-editor',
    'send-attachment-to-editor', 'save-attachment-order', 'heartbeat', 'get-revision-diffs',
    'save-user-color-scheme', 'update-widget', 'query-themes', 'parse-embed', 'set-attachment-thumbnail',
    'parse-media-shortcode', 'destroy-sessions', 'install-plugin', 'update-plugin', 'press-this-save-post',
    'press-this-add-category', 'crop-image', 'generate-password', 'save-wporg-username', 'delete-plugin',
    'search-plugins', 'search-install-plugins', 'activate-plugin', 'update-theme', 'delete-theme',
    'install-theme', 'get-post-thumbnail-html',
);

// Deprecated
$core_actions_post[] = 'wp-fullscreen-save-post';

// Register core Ajax calls.
if ( ! empty( $_GET['action'] ) && in_array( $_GET['action'], $core_actions_get ) )
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_GET['action'], 'wp_ajax_' . str_replace( '-', '_', $_GET['action'] ), 1 );

if ( ! empty( $_POST['action'] ) && in_array( $_POST['action'], $core_actions_post ) )
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_POST['action'], 'wp_ajax_' . str_replace( '-', '_', $_POST['action'] ), 1 );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_heartbeat', 'wp_ajax_nopriv_heartbeat', 1 );

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    /**
     * Fires authenticated Ajax actions for logged-in users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the Ajax action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
} else {
    /**
     * Fires non-authenticated Ajax actions for logged-out users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the Ajax action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
}
// Default status
die( '0' );